# stream objects in c++ i will be very useful

Tags: c++

what are stream objects in c++. i will be very grateful thank you

Answer (score 3):

For a start, you can see the hierarchy of the I/O stream classes in C++ in this diagram:

[image]

And the small description you can read here : [IOstream Library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/), and rest you can read from your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Stream objects implement input and output. Objects implementing input are derived from `istream`, those implementing output derive from `ostream`, and ones with both derive from `iostream` which is a subclass of both `istream` and `ostream`.

Behind an `istream`, `ostream`, or `iostream` object is a `streambuf` object which implements the guts of the actual I/O. The Standard Library provides for I/O to the console (`cin` and `cout`), to a file (`fstream`), or to a string buffer (`stringstream`).